# How to serialize in Django Rest Framework with custom fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say my model is:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to have a serializer that receives multiple fields and then combine them to create an email. For example:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first = serializers.CharField()
    second = serializers.CharField()
    third = serializers.CharField()
```

It would convert {"first": "user", "second": "example", "third": "org"} to a new Contact object with the email 'user@example.org'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override serializer's `create` method:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first = serializers.CharField()
    second = serializers.CharField()
    third = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = '{0}@{1}.{2}'.format(validated_data['first'], validated_data['second'], validated_data['third'])
        instance = Contact.objects.create(email=email)
        return instance
```